# How to design a custom UITableView like Google Drive uses including animation while drilling down and up in the folder structure.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, folderbrowserdialog

I would like to display file folder structure exactly like in Google Drive and with the proper animation. When we are drilling down then the resulting view enters from the right and vise-versa.

> NB: Showing the structure is not the question rather the proper
>   animation.

[image]

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried using the methods:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
//perform changes to data
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

With each section being folders. So initially a bunch of sections with 0 cells, and the once you tap a section, you insert cells for that section, and reference that through the paths array.